# SystemVerilog Instantiated Modules Share Inputs When They Shouldn't (Easy Solution)?

Tags: module, counter, instantiation, system-verilog, hdl

I am having a small issue here in when I instantiated my modules. I am using a generate loop to create 100 instances of 2 counters (16 & 32 bit counters). Each counter should have their own independent controls (UPDN & EN), but they share a clock and a reset.

*Module Descriptions:*

*SAT_COUNTER.sv   // SIMPLE COUNTER MODULE*

*TWO_SC.sv        // INSTANTIATES TWO SAT_COUNTER MODULES (16 BIT & 32 BIT 
COUNTERS)*

*GEN_SC.sv        // INSTANTIATES 100 MODULES OF TWO_SC MODULES*

*tb_GEN_SC.sv     // TESTBENCH*

I am sure that my problem is in the GEN_SC module where I instantiate all 100..

I appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

```
module SAT_COUNTER(
    COUNT,          // SCALABLE COUNT OUTPUT
    CLK,            // CLOCK
    al_RST,         // ACTIVE LOW RESET
    UPDN,           // COUNTER WILL COUNT: UP = 1; DN = 0;
    EN);            // ENABLE

    parameter WIDTH = 8;

    input CLK, al_RST, UPDN, EN;
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] COUNT;

    ...

endmodule

 //**********************

module TWO_SC(
  COUNT1,       // N-BIT COUNTER OUTPUT
  COUNT2,       // M-BIT COUNTER OUTPUT
  CLK,          // CLOCK
  al_RST,       // ACTIVE-LOW RESET
  UPDN,         // DIR. CONTROL
  EN);          // ENABLE

  parameter WIDTH1 = 16;
  parameter WIDTH2 = 32;

  input CLK, al_RST;
  input [1:0] UPDN, EN;
  output [WIDTH1-1:0] COUNT1;
  output [WIDTH2-1:0] COUNT2;

  SAT_COUNTER   #(WIDTH1) GSC1(.COUNT(COUNT1), .CLK(CLK), .al_RST(al_RST), .UPDN(UPDN[0]), .EN(EN[0]));
  SAT_COUNTER   #(WIDTH2) GSC2(.COUNT(COUNT2), .CLK(CLK), .al_RST(al_RST), .UPDN(UPDN[1]), .EN(EN[1]));

endmodule

//**********************

module GEN_SC(
  COUNT1,       // COUNT1
  COUNT2,       // COUNT2
  CLK,          // CLOCK
  al_RST,       // ACTIVE-LOW RESET
  UPDN,         // DIR. CONTROL
  EN);          // ENABLE

  parameter MOD_COUNT = 100;
  parameter WIDTH1 = 16;
  parameter WIDTH2 = 32;

  input CLK, al_RST;
  input [1:0] UPDN [MOD_COUNT-1:0];
  input [1:0] EN [MOD_COUNT-1:0];
  output [WIDTH1-1:0] COUNT1;
  output [WIDTH2-1:0] COUNT2;

  genvar j;

      generate
        for(j = 0; j < MOD_COUNT; j++) begin: SC
          TWO_SC    #(.WIDTH1(WIDTH1), .WIDTH2(WIDTH2))    TWOCOUNTERS(.COUNT1(COUNT1), .COUNT2(COUNT2), .CLK(CLK), .al_RST(al_RST), .UPDN(UPDN[j]), .EN(EN[j]));
         end
      endgenerate


endmodule

//**********************

module tb_GEN_SC();

parameter MOD_COUNT = 100;
parameter WIDTH1 = 16;
parameter WIDTH2 = 32;

  reg CLK, al_RST;
  reg [1:0] UPDN [MOD_COUNT-1:0];
  reg [1:0] EN [MOD_COUNT-1:0];
  wire [WIDTH1-1:0] COUNT1;
  wire [WIDTH2-1:0] COUNT2;

  GEN_SC    #(.WIDTH1(WIDTH1), .WIDTH2(WIDTH2))    UUT(COUNT1, COUNT2, CLK, al_RST, UPDN, EN);

    initial begin
CLK = 1'b1;
  forever
    #5 CLK = ~CLK;
  end

    initial
    $monitorb("%d  COUNT = %b (%d) | UPDN = %b | EN = %b | COUNT = %b (%d) | UPDN = %b | EN = %b | al_RST = %b | CLK = %b", $time, UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.COUNT1, UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.COUNT1, UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.UPDN[0], UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.EN[0], UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.COUNT1, UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.COUNT1, UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.UPDN[0], UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.EN[0], al_RST, CLK);

    initial begin
    $vcdpluson;
            UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 1; UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 1; EN = 0; al_RST = 1;
    #10                                           UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 0;         al_RST = 0;           // RESET COUNTER
    #10                                                                                 EN = 1; al_RST = 1;         // ENABLE COUNTER AND COUNT UP (HITS MAX)
    #200    UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 0; UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 1; EN = 1;                     // BEGIN TO COUNT DOWN
    #10                                       EN = 0;
    #60                                       EN = 3;
//      #230    UPDN = 1; UPDN = 0;
    #3017                                     al_RST = 0;
    #100                                      al_RST = 1;
    #20 $finish;
    end
```

/////////// ERRORS I GET /////////////////

Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side
tb_GEN_SC.sv, 34
  Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
  The offending expression is : tb_GEN_SC.UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN
  Source info: tb_GEN_SC.UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 1;

Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side
tb_GEN_SC.sv, 34
  Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
  The offending expression is : tb_GEN_SC.UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN
  Source info: tb_GEN_SC.UUT.SC[99].TWOCOUNTERS.GSC1.UPDN = 1;

Error-[IUDA] Incompatible dimensions
tb_GEN_SC.sv, 34
  Incompatible unpacked dimensions in assignment
  Arrays with incompatible unpacked dimensions  cannot be used in assignments,
  initializations and instantiations.

Error-[ICTA] Incompatible complex type
tb_GEN_SC.sv, 34
  Incompatible complex type assignment
  Type of source expression is incompatible with type of target expression. 
  Mismatching types cannot be used in assignments, initializations and 
  instantiations. The type of the target is 'reg[1:0]$[99:0]', while the type 
  of the source is 'int'.
  Source Expression: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just one UPDB and one EN port in port list. So how you wana apply different UPDN and EN to instances?

An idea is to define an array with size of MOD_COUNT so that each element has its own control input. then in genvar loop you can use the index. like this:

```
input [1:0] UPDN  [MOD_COUNT-1:0];
input [1:0] EN [MOD_COUNT-1:0];
```

...

```
generate
    for(j = 0; j < MOD_COUNT; j++) begin: SC

  TWO_SC    #(.WIDTH1(WIDTH1), .WIDTH2(WIDTH2))    TWOCOUNTERS(.COUNT1(COUNT1),
 .COUNT2(COUNT2), .CLK(CLK), .al_RST(al_RST),      .UPDN(UPDN[j]), .EN(EN[j]));

 end
  endgenerate
```

Comment: Hey Laleh! I appreciate you taking the time to help me. That's what I've begun to experiment with. I'm using a multi-dimensional array. I thought of having UPDN and EN be 2 bits wide so that one bit for UPDN & EN would correspond to the 2 counters I instantiated in TWO_SC. So, what I want should be: input [1:0] UPDN [MOD_COUNT-1:0] ..right? Same for EN.

Comment: Nice! That's what I had going.. good to know! Now I'm having trouble in my test bench in creating the vectors for each counter.. I edited my test bench above. Can you please take a look? I know it's not a great test bench but it'll do for now. This is an error and I know it's because UPDN is not a reg..

Error-[IBLHS-NONREG] Illegal behavioral left hand side
tb_GEN_SC.sv, 35
  Non reg type is not valid on the left hand side of this assignment
  The offending expression is : tb_GEN_SC.UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.UPDN[0]
  Source info: tb_GEN_SC.UUT.SC[87].TWOCOUNTERS.UPDN[0] = 1;

Comment: UPDN[87]! What's that? UPDN, EN are 2d. In tb they are declared 1D. that's the problem. By the way, why parameters are outside of tb module? is that ok in SV?

Comment: Hahaha! I know that some of the vectors don't make sense. I did that to try different ways to change the inputs and see what worked. I have that line commented out in my test bench (tb) & I also have both inputs being 2D in my tb. Do I need to make them regs if I want to change the inputs? I feel like there's no need to make then regs. Hmm.. I thought it was okay to leave them outside a module but I looked further online and it said they must be contained within a module. I'll ask my prof. next week!

Comment: In test bench inputs of instantiated module MUST be reg and output wire, Always.

Comment: Right! I know that much, but what about in GEN_SC.sv & TWO_SC.sv?

Comment: Input inside module is always wire. In this two modules you don't change outputs in behavioral blocks, so they don't need to be reg. Wire is ok.

Comment: Cool cool! Okay, I've updated my source code to what I currently have as well as the different errors I'm currently getting. My problem now is accessing the independent controls for each counter... shoot me!

Comment: I answered your first question. So you should mark that as accepted answer! You can use points I've already mentioned to correct your code. This type of step by step debugging is not what SOF is really for!

Comment: For sure Laleh! You've been a big help and I greatly appreciate it!